# Removing part of an exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have come across a statement in my textbook which I do not understand and have searched online for an answer but this specific case does not seem to come up 
$x_{n}=(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$  can be rearranged to  $x_{n}=2(\frac{1}{2})^{n}$. I am not sure how you remove only part of the exponent. Is there a general rule for removing part of an exponent that works in any expression?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\times\frac12\times2=\left(\frac12\right)^n\times2$$